# Sorting out the Correlation Matrix in range in Excel or in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I've a BIG data set which I have exported using this code:

```
(corr.style.background_gradient(cmap='coolwarm').to_excel("S:.......ABC.xlsx", engine="openpyxl"))
```

How I have a huge data ranging between 1 to -1 and I want only the data having range of 0.3 to 0.933 and -0.3 to -0.933.

How to I do that?

Eg of the data:

[image: The dataset]

Comment: The problem is that some rows might have some columns with values within the desired range and other columns outside that range. Do you want to discard the whole row in that case or do you want to replace the values outside the range with `np.nan` or 0 for instance?

Comment: I want to remove the columns NOT having range between 0.3 to 0.933 and -0.3 to -0.933

Comment: I answered how to do that, but be aware that all the columns will have at least one value=1 on the diagonal of the correlation matrix..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first find the columns to keep where all the values are in the range like this

```
columns_to_keep1 = [col for col in corr.columns if not (any(corr[col] < 0.3) or any(corr[col] > 0.933))]
columns_to_keep2 = [col for col in corr.columns if not (any(corr[col] > -0.3) or any(corr[col] < -0.933))]
```

The snippet above will check all the columns in your data frame and add to the final list (through list comprehension) only those columns where all the values are in the desired range.

Then you can select only the `columns_to_keep` columns from your dataframe like such

```
corr = corr[columns_to_keep1 + columns_to_keep2]
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I was stuck to this for so long. Thanks again!! :)

Comment: I am happy I was helpful :) if the answer solved your problem please remember to accept it